# Get a Value from a column based on Effective Date in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

```
|Part| Date         | Price   |
|A   | 1-May-2021   |10       |
|B   | 1-June-2021  |20       |
```

Table 2

```
|Part| Date         | Quantity |
|A   | 15-May-2021  |4       |
|B   | 25-June-2021 |5       |
```

Need Output as below

```
|Part| Date         | Quantity | Price   | Amount  
|A   | 15-May-2021  |4         | 10      | 40   
|B   | 25-June-2021 |5         | 20      | 100
```

So on the effective date of 15-May-21, the price was 10 for Part A , so it should bring me the effective rate and multiply with Qty

Comment: I just notice `Amount` value for `B` is `80`... is that a typo?

Comment: Yes , sorry its a typo... its 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Date columns are actual sane date types and not insane/broken varchar types:

```
SELECT t.Part, t.Date, t.Quantity, t.Price, t.Price*t.Quantity As Amount
FROM (
    SELECT t2.*, t1.Price, row_number() over (PARTITION BY t2.Part ORDER BY t1.Date) rn
    FROM Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Part = t2.Part and t2.Date <= t1.Date
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: This answer have a typo at `t.Price*t.Quanity`, mistake of `t2.Price` where there's no `Price` column for `Table2` provided by OP and `t.Date` return different date value than the expected result. If all that are corrected, then it does get the expected result.

Comment: Typos are fixed.

Comment: `Unknown column 't.Quanity' in 'field list'` https://dbfiddle.uk/iyuHtLwh

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Date` column really using that date format? If so, then here's a couple of suggestion:

1. You can `JOIN` them by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the month & year from `Date` column:

```
SELECT t1.Part, t2.Date, t2.Quantity, t1.Price, t2.Quantity*t1.Price AS "Amount"
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.Part=t2.Part
   AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.date,'-',-2)=  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.date,'-',-2)
```

2. OR you can `JOIN` them by using [EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) to extract the year & month from a converted `Date` column. Using [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), you can convert the `Date` to MySQL standard date format provided that the date value is consistent with the [DATE_FORMAT specifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
 SELECT t1.Part, t2.Date, t2.Quantity, t1.Price, t2.Quantity*t1.Price AS "Amount"
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.Part=t2.Part
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(t1.date,'%e-%M-%Y'))
      =EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%e-%M-%Y'))
```

I think that those two options above are effective in most cases. However, I personally would prefer using the proper MySQL standard date datatype instead. In that case, I'd add another date column and use that for the date function:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN mDate DATE;
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN mDate DATE;

UPDATE Table1 SET mDate=STR_TO_DATE(date,'%e-%M-%Y');
UPDATE Table2 SET mDate=STR_TO_DATE(date,'%e-%M-%Y');

SELECT * FROM Table1;
SELECT * FROM Table2;

SELECT t1.Part, t2.Date, t2.Quantity, t1.Price, t2.Quantity*t1.Price AS "Amount"
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.Part=t2.Part
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t1.mDate)=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t2.mDate);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ieGwmpi0)

Comment: My bad, I was so fixated on the year month matching that I forgot to include `Part` columns matching in `ON` for the `JOIN`.